# WSO2 BAM New Error - SSTableBatchOpen

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

Yesterday, I configured BAM with AM and MySQL.
But, today, when I have rebooted the system, a new error appears.
This is not the only problem I have encountered.

Here is the error :

```
[2014-05-14 09:00:08,372] ERROR {org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon} -  Exception in thread Thread[SSTableBatchOpen:1,5,main]
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.EstimatedHistogram$EstimatedHistogramSerializer.deserialize(EstimatedHistogram.java:241)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableMetadata$SSTableMetadataSerializer.deserialize(SSTableMetadata.java:217)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableMetadata$SSTableMetadataSerializer.deserialize(SSTableMetadata.java:206)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:171)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:153)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader$1.run(SSTableReader.java:242)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Where could it come from?